# Custom UIBezierPath in swift (Arc trouble)

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I write this code :

```
let leftUpPath = UIBezierPath()
leftUpPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40))
leftUpPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40),
    radius: 10,
    startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
    endAngle: CGFloat(3*Double.pi),
    clockwise: true)
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 50))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 50))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 80, y: 30))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 30))
```

and this show me this in my storyboard:

[image: Story Board]

but I want this :

[image: what I want]

If anyone have the solution, I think my trouble is where I draw the Arc... Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the start and end angles flipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point and the arc were incorrect. You need:

```
let leftUpPath = UIBezierPath()
leftUpPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 30))
leftUpPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40),
                  radius: 10,
                  startAngle: .pi * 3 / 2,
                  endAngle: .pi,
                  clockwise: false)
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 50))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 90, y: 50))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 80, y: 30))
leftUpPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 30))
```

Comment: If you're inspecting the path in a playground or the debugger, it's drawn in the usual mathematical geometry where y increases up. If you draw it in graphics context created by UIKit (e.g. `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`), it's drawn in the usual UIKit geometry where y increases down.

Comment: @robmayoff with `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()` ?